# Tasksel with E: read, still have 1070 to read but none left

Tags: apt, ubuntu-10.04

I try to use tasksel to install webserver

But When I run tasksel

i just get `E: read, still have 1070 to read but none left`

Run On `Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS \n \l`

Kernel `3.18.20-nce-amd64`